# How to invoke parent class function inside a asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to trigger the `pushBulkData` function inside stream reading event.

I tried with

```
this.pushBulkData(row, importData);
```

I know it won't work because it this has the separate scope here

and

```
taskController.pushBulkData(row, importData);
```

and this cannot be done all the time.

Would `bind` work?

```
class taskController{
    async import(path){

        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(path);

        src.pipe(dest);

        let importData = [];

        src.on('end', function() {
            fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(require('csv-parser')(['name', 'status']))
            .on('data', function (row) {
                //this makes error
                this.pushBulkData(row, importData);
            })
            .on('end', function () {

                // We are done
            })
        });
        src.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error on upload file'); });
    }

    pushBulkData(row, importData){
        console.log('row', row);         

        importData.push(
            {
                name          : row.name,
                status        : row.status}
        );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to arrow functions since they don't have their own "this" context. So, the parent class "this" will be what it refers to:

```
    src.on('end', () => {
        fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(require('csv-parser')(['name', 'status']))
        .on('data', row => {
            //this makes error
            this.pushBulkData(row, importData);
        })
        .on('end', function () {

            // We are done
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes bind will work here. but you can use fat arrow function so you won't loose your context.

```
src.on('end', () => {
    fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(require('csv-parser')(['name', 'status']))
    .on('data', row => {
        //this won't make error
        this.pushBulkData(row, importData);
    })
    .on('end', function () {

        // We are done
    })
});
```

Or if you don't want to use arrow function then you can save `this` to another variable and use it.

```
async import(path){

    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(path);

    src.pipe(dest);

    let importData = [];
    const _this = this;
    src.on('end', function() {
        fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(require('csv-parser')(['name', 'status']))
        .on('data', function (row) {
            //this won't make error
            _this.pushBulkData(row, importData);
        })
        .on('end', function () {

            // We are done
        })
    });
    src.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error on upload file'); });
}
```